# How to test canvas with testWidgets in a flutter mobile app project

Tags: flutter, testing, dart, flutter-test

I was reading about how to build tests for flutter app widgets with the testWidgets function, like this test which comes by default when creating a new flutter project:

```dart
// <project>/test/widget_test.dart
void main() {
  testWidgets('Counter increments smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(CounterApp());
    // validate counter starts at zero
    expect(find.text('0'), findsOneWidget);
    
    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
    await tester.pump();

    expect(find.text('0'), findsNothing);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsOneWidget);
  }
}
```

But how would one test a canvas to see if the drawings/patterns and paragraphs are being displayed correctly? Does the finder object finds a Text widget if I draw a paragraph with `canvas.drawParagraph(...)`? I couldn't find info about this in the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing).

Comment: You might want to look into using [`matchesGoldenFile`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/matchesGoldenFile.html) to compare screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Testing Canvas in general (no matter the technology) should be performed using *visual testing* (or *visual regression testing*).

[`flutter_test`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/flutter_test-library.html) package provides [`matchesGoldenFile`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/matchesGoldenFile.html) function that makes it possible. There's a nice [tutorial on Flutter's Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Writing-a-golden-file-test-for-package:flutter) that will guide you through.